# Parsing a String of JSON for attribute into multiple sends to the same endpoint

Tags: javascript, json

My problem seems simple but I've hit a wall looking into it. Unfortunately, I'm not too terribly deep into javascript but I understand its going to require it. Basically, I'm having one service do a GET on a server that provides all of the information into a bulk drop. I can take all the attributes that qualify and combine them into a single json string. 
I need to pass that string to another platform that will divide the attribute into multiple sends and post to an endpoint.
The database I'm posting to (at the moment) cannot handle bulk uploads so this seems to be the best option, but I'm not sure if its possible.

```
{
  "email_address": ["jon@gmail.com", "sally@yahoo.com", "bobbert@msn.com"]
}
```

Into

```
[
  {"email_address":"john@gmail.com"},
  {"email_address":"sally@yahoo.com"},
  {"email_address":"bobbert@msn.com"}
]
```

Any help is appreciated!

[Edit: Quickly made a change to the sample code above. Meant for it to be an array of email address & forgot to format it correctly]

Comment: the JSON you show is not valid. The first key is `email_address` with a value of `jon@gmail.com` and the second key doesn't exist. Did you mean for `email_address` to be an array?

Comment: Yeah - sorry was trying to quickly type this out and realized it was supposed to be an array and that I need to parse the array between multiple sends. I'll quickly change the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your object structure but you can use something like this.

```js
let obj = {
  email_address: ["jon@gmail.com", "sally@yahoo.com", "bobbert@msn.com"],
};

let objects = [];

for (key in obj) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
    for (val of obj[key]) {
      objects.push({
        [key]: val
      });
    }
  }
}

console.log(objects);
```